# MessagingCenter.Subscribe in not listening to outsider messages?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm loading the page's data in the `OnAppearing` method,  but this causes loading data in situations where it doesn't change, like calling PopupAsync() from another page. so I thought the messaging center would help. I made a flag field in the page, and subscribed to any message coming from outside to decide whether to update data or not,
for example this from the MenuViewModel (when the user first opens the page, so I need to load data):

```
var p = new FeedbackListPage();
MessagingCenter.Send(this, "loadData", "1");
await Navigation.PushAsync(p);
```

and in the `FeedbackListPage`'s constructor:

```
InitializeComponent();
BindingContext = vm = new FeedbackViewModel(Navigation);
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<string>(this, "loadData", ( _loadData) =>
   {
      loadDataStr = _loadData;
   });
```

and in the `OnAppearing`:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            if (loadDataStr=="1")
               vm.OnLoadFeedbacks();
        }
```

the problem is that the Subscribe's action is never called!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

The API for MessagingCenter:

**1**.`Subscribe<TSender> (object subscriber, string message, Action<TSender> callback, TSender source = null)`

**2**.`Subscribe<TSender, TArgs> (object subscriber, string message,Action<TSender, TArgs> callback, TSender source = null)`

So, if you want to pass an `Argument` using `MessageCenter`, you should define both `Sender` and `Args`:

```
  MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage,string>(this, "loadData", (sender,_loadData) =>
            {
                loadDataStr = _loadData;
            });
```

Refer: [messaging-center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center)

Comment: Thanks, Can I define multiple senders with only one Subscription , currently I want to listen from two ViewModels and have two identical `MessagingCenter.Subscribe..`  differ only the the `TSender`

Comment: No, you need two `MessagingCenter.Subscribe..` as you have to define the type of `TSender` first.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

use `MessagingCenter.Send` to send the signal when you want to update the data from any page and then in your ViewModel's constructor use `MessagingCenter.Subscribe` to perform the needed action

**Send:**

```
MessagingCenter.Send<namespace.App>((namespace.App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "update");
```

**Subscribe:**

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<namespace.App>((namespace.App)Application.Current, "update", (sender) => {
                // update - get data
            });
```